# Configure Remote Desktop to resize resolution to connecting client window?

Tags: windows-server-2008, resolution, remote-desktop

I used to work in a place where we had Windows Server 2008 R2 VMs, and when I would remote to them, the desktop resolution would always resize itself to the size of the window I was connecting with, so there would never be any scrollbars.

Now I'm working at a place where we have Windows Server 2008 R2 on a VM that I'm remoting to, and the server's resolution seems fixed.  And it's slightly larger than my external monitor, so I always get scrollbars, and have to scroll around to get to the Start menu etc.  I'm finding this annoying.

How do you configure Remote Desktop on the server so that it resizes to the size of the connecting window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is even better option. Use [Remote Desktop Connection Manager 2.7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44989) from Microsoft, but depending on your needs I recommend older version [Remote Desktop Manager 2.2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21101) if you need to scale up to full screen.

Not just that you can create groups and list all remote machines that you connect to, but you can also specify screen resolution for each one! 
Create new server and in Remote Desktop Tab choose screen resolution. 
The main benefit is that when you select Full Screen from Session menu, *your host screen is filled up, just like VNC!*
I had different problem, my screen is 1920x1080 and when connecting to remote, everything was too small, fonts, etc. So, I set RDP resolution to custom 1536x864 and everything is scaled up nicely, fonts are bigger, etc.

Comment: Aha!  That's the ticket.  I was already using RDCM, just didn't know there was an option to set the resolution.  The option I was looking for there is "Same as client area" -- makes the remote desktop always fit into my client window.

Answer (score 0):

If you are establishing a connection from a Microsoft Windows system, have you tried mstsc with width and height parameters in pixels from the command line on your remote system to establish an RDP connection? E.g.:

```
mstsc /w:1024 /h:768 /v:server1.example.com
```

Or you could try the span parameter, which "matches the remote desktop width and height with the local virtual desktop, spanning across multiple monitors, if necessary. To span across monitors, the monitors must be arranged to form a rectangle." E.g.:

```
mstsc /span /v:server1.example.com
```